# Optimisations for a series of functions in Haskell

Tags: haskell, math, optimization

I am trying to do problem 254 in project euler and arrived at this set of functions and refactor in Haskell:

```
f  n = sum $ map fac (decToList n)
sf n = sum $ decToList (f n) 
g  i = head [ n | n <- [1..], sf n == i]
sg i = sum $ decToList (g i)

answer = sum [ sg i | i <- [1 .. 150] ]
```

Where:

- `f (n)` finds the sum of the factorials of each digit in `n`
- `sf (n)` is the sum of the digits in the result of `f (n)`
- `g (i)` is the smallest integer solution for `sf (i)`. As there can be many results for `sf (i)`
- `sg (i)` is the sum of the digits in the result of `g (i)`

But not long into running the compiled version of this script, it sucked up all my RAM. Is there a better way to implement the function `g (i)`? If so what can they be and how could I go about it?

EDIT:

Just out of clarity, my functions for:

`fac` is :

```
`fac 0 = 1`

`fac n = n * fac (n-1)`
```

`decToList` which makes a number into a list:

```
decToList1 x = reverse $ decToList' x
where
decToList' 0 = []
decToList' y = let (a,b) = quotRem y 10 in [b] ++ decToList' a
```

Although I did since update them to Yairchu's solution for optimisation sake.

Comment: I don't know Haskell that well, but your last line of code has mismatched brackets, which is almost always a typo.

Comment: Hi,this is Euler **254** ,so I won't expect the brute force algorithm would work. However,I can not think up a smarter algorithm so far. My program has run more a hour but still did not get g(50)..

Comment: @Chris Lutz: you are right. it was a typo

Comment: It seems that the first 36 results are achieved relatively quickly, and then it slows to a crawl.

Comment: On a new observation, it seems that after `g (21)`, all the resultsfor `g(i)` end in 9

Comment: I suggest you do the math how big a number needs to get to arrive at 150. In other words, brute force won't solve this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The memory problem might lie in decToList or fac.

I ran it with

```
fac = product . enumFromTo 1
decToList = map (read . return) . show
main = print answer
```

And it didn't come near to sucking all my RAM, it did not finish, though.

btw: I suspect an advanced project Euler problem to be harder than that. therefore this algorithm won't do.

Comment: The factorial and decimal to list functions in this problem are trivial i guess, unless the value for g(i) becomes incredibly large.
But it seemed so simple! Perhaps I'll ask my maths teachers and that chemistry teacher who is also an ace at computer science tomorrow.

Comment: @Jonno_FTW: Even though they are trivial, for debugging a mysterious bug, one requires the complete picture